# GCC plugin with method was declared inside class

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-plugins

I am developing an GCC plugin to process AST in SSA form. 
I create a callback run everytime after SSA form of function was compiled.

Here is my code

```
char* get_name_node(tree node) {
     // return string represent node name
}

void execute_plugin_pass() { 
     printf("%s\n", get_name_node(cfun->decl));
}

struct opt_pass plugin_pass = 
{
    GIMPLE_PASS,
    "plugin_pass",
    0,
    execute_plugin_pass,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    0,
    TV_PLUGIN_RUN,
    PROP_gimple_any,
    0,
    0,
    0,
    0
};



extern "C" int
plugin_init(plugin_name_args* info, plugin_gcc_version* ver)
{
    struct register_pass_info pass_info;
    pass_info.reference_pass_name = where;
    pass_info.pass = pass;
    pass_info.ref_pass_instance_number = 0;
    pass_info.pos_op = PASS_POS_INSERT_AFTER;
    register_callback("plugin", PLUGIN_PASS_MANAGER_SETUP, NULL, &pass_info);
    return 0;   
}
```

But above code not run for method of class which was declare inside class declaration
For example, with this code

```
class A {
    void method1();
    void method2() {
         // run some code here
    }
};

void A::method1() {
    // run some code here
}
```

My plugin only run for method1, but dont run for method2

At begining, i think this problems is because method2() will be considered as inline function, so i add option -fno-inline when run plugin. But it doesn't work

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the issue is where to insert your pass in the executed passes. Remember that the set and order of executed GCC passes vary with the optimization (so is different with `-O0`,  `-O1`,  `-O2`,  ...). I don't understand where you are inserting it.

I also sometimes have the same issue of choosing where should I insert my pass. I often have a trial and error approach. Look into file `gcc/passes.c` of the GCC source tree.

If you need the SSA form of Gimple, consider inserting after the `"ssa"` pass or maybe after `"phiopt"`.

If you don't need SSA, consider inserting after `"cfg"`.

Out of curiosity, could you explain what your GCC plugin is doing?

Did you consider using [GCC MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/) (MELT is a high level domain specific language to code GCC extensions) for your work?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. My plugin was inserting after "ssa" pass. I make this plugin to generate CDFG for cpp source code. I didn't notice about the optimization. Let me check it again.